# Detecting ALL local devices wity Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mobile, detection, modem

I used a lot of codes for this operation. I just want to get all devices which is connected on my modem.

I just get laptops, but cant get mobiles.

This was my code;

```
import socket
import thread
import os

fullList=[]

def getHost(ip):
    try:
        a=socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
        if(fullList.count(a)==0):
            print a
            fullList.append(a)
            a=1
    except:
        a=1

cc=1
while(1):
    for x in range(1,254):
        try:
            thread.start_new_thread(getHost, ("192.168.1."+str(x), ) )
        except:
            a=1
    cc+=1
    if(cc==1000):
        print "test..... Count: "+str(len(fullList))
        print fullList
        cc=1
```

what should i do for now? what should i look?

Comment: `while(0):`? Why?

Comment: @KlausD. thx for pointing :))) i fixed

Comment: In Python the typical style would be `while True:` (no parentheses, True instead of `1` and a space between a keyword and an expression).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using python-nmap and manipulating its results.

https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/